# Using LINQ to CSV with additional headers

Tags: c#, csv

I am currently using LINQtoCSV to read some csv's. The problem i have at the moment is that i want to be able to add additional information to the header, which will be applied to all entries in the list. For example my current csv:

```
StartStateId,Event,EndStateId
State A,MX-000A,State B
State B,MX-000A,State B
State C,MX-000A,State B
State D,MX-000A,State B
State A,MX-000C,State B
State B,MX-000C,State C
State C,MX-000C,State D
State A,MX-000B,State A
State B,MX-000B,State A
State C,MX-000B,State A
State D,MX-000B,State A
```

What i want is to be able to read a header like:

```
MX-000C, MX-000A
StartStateId,Event,EndStateId
State A,MX-000A,State B
State B,MX-000A,State B
State C,MX-000A,State B
State D,MX-000A,State B
State A,MX-000C,State B
State B,MX-000C,State C
State C,MX-000C,State D
State A,MX-000B,State A
State B,MX-000B,State A
State C,MX-000B,State A
State D,MX-000B,State
```

And to be able to read this first line seperately. Is there any way to do this using this library (seeing as the support from the site isnt that strong there might be users here using the library too) or should i just implement a reader by myself?

(The format of this header line is not important to me it is just about reading it)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The thing is that i have to declare a CsvFileDescription for this library stating how the data is formatted in the file, which is fine for what i have been using it so far, however when i try to add lines like these it does not read them obviously, and i get errors that the file is not compliant to the description.

Comment: This sounds like it is by design. If your input doesn't match the expected description of said input, then it should throw exceptions/errors.

Comment: Ye that was what i was affraid of, time to implement one of my own then :)

Comment: If you do have to implement your own and you want a definition/description to verify it, you may want to look at using xml/xsd rather than csv. If you don't need the verification you may want to consider json.

Comment: I need to work with CSV's because of the tech we are using, else i would have chosen XML a long time ago :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently not possible in this library, so i have implemented my own parser to do the job for me